# Android - Restart service, which was forced-stopped (not app, service only), when app is still running

Tags: android, push-notification, android-service

I am developing a background push service for my app, this service starts when the app starts. Everything works fine, except for one problem.

If user force-stops the PushService using task manager (just the service, not the app), app still works properly, but it will not receive any push message unless it is closed and started again.

So is there any way that I can check/restart the service when app is brought back to foreground (after user comes back from task manager)

Answer (score 0):

you can try on service class ***start_sticky***
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY